# How can I call an image in menustrip and hide it?

Tags: c#, winforms

I was wondering how can I get this done since I'll use it in notifying the user whether a certain tab has values in it.

So what I wanted to happen is that the image will appear when it has values, and when it is empty, the image will be hidden.

[image]

Note that the image will reappear when a certain tab has values in it.

Comment: Create an event handler for the Menu open event. Depending on the status you are basing your show/not show decision on, modify the menu item's properties

Comment: That ToolStripItem has an Image property.  Set it back to null to hide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this by having the image appear when a certain table has values in it, unless it is empty, then the image in the menutoolstrip won't come out

Here's my code:

```
private void Home_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GetPurchase())
        {
            forApprovalToolStripMenuItem.Image = Properties.Resources.sign_check_icon;
        }
        else
        {
            forApprovalToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
        }


        itemRequestsToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
        forApprovalToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;

    }

    bool GetPurchase()
    {
        bool withPending;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetConnection()))
        {
            con.Open();
            string query = @"SELECT POID FROM purchaseorder_table WHERE status='Pending'";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                return withPending = cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null ? false : true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

i would recomend you to use the [DisplayStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.displaystyle?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_ToolStripItem_DisplayStyle) property of a [ToolStripMenuItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem?view=netframework-4.7.2).

You can test this by just adding the mouseenter and mouseleave event to your control like in this example. This way you do not delete the image (by setting it to null) like proposed in one of the comments above.

```
 private void testToolStripMenuItem_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as ToolStripMenuItem).DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Text;
    }

    private void testToolStripMenuItem_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as ToolStripMenuItem).DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.ImageAndText;
    }
```

I hope this helps you further.

Cheers

Comment: I tried applying it yet it doesn't do anything. I think it lacks something

Comment: @JonathanSumilang It works just fine. Be very carefull to use the **correct name** of the toolStripMenuItem.

Comment: I tried applying it several times but It doesn't work well on my project, I need this event to trigger whenever a certain event happens like when items that is needing approval are piling up, then the image will appear on the tool strip menu and then after approving all of it, the image will be gone or if there are no requests made

Comment: @JonathanSumilang The code provided was just a example of how to realize this with MouseEnter and MouselLeave. Why i choosed this two events was in order to give you a easy visual feeling of the implementation. You can very well to this anywhere in code. Maybe you can provide me more in depth example of your source code and i can help you better.